# Parallel speedup issue for a method to get query in java

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I have the following method to execute queries on a dataset containing literals (such as p(a,b),q(c,d),r(a,d) . . .). Literals are stored in `Map<String, Queue<Literal>>` data structure where key is their predicates (such as p,q,r,...) and ArrayDequeue of Literals. This method is executed within a backtracking algorithm to find instantiation for a rule like:
u(x,z) :- p(x,y), q(y,z).

The following method is executing many times within backtracking algorithm and try to look for literals that are matched with the query parameters (for example teta={(x=a),(y=b)} & predicate=q, arity=2). 
I have many rules and each rule instantiation is done by a thread (I am using threadpool using ExecutorService). The following method is my HotSpot. However, I cannot achieve desired speedup (only 2 times with running four threads). To simulate CPU work I added Thread.Sleep(1) in the method then achieved expected speedup (3.9)! Do I have a problem in data locality or cache miss? Is my following structure cache friendly enough?

Besides my allocation rate for objects is 13 byte/sec and I am running the application on a machine with 4 CPU cores with 1.8 JDK and running 4 threads.

```
private void indexFactsWithJointVars(String[][] teta, String predicate, int arity){

    Map<String, Queue<Literal>>
        indexedFactsWithJointVars = new HashMap<>();

    // indexedFactsWithAllFreeVars also has Map<String, Queue<Literal>> data structure
    Queue<Literal> literals = indexedFactsWithAllFreeVars.get(predicate);

    Queue<Literal> matchedLiterals = new ArrayDeque<>();

    for (Literal edb_lit: literals){
        boolean match = true;
        for (int i=0; i<teta.length; i++){
            int position = Integer.parseInt(teta[i][0]);
            String attribute = teta[i][1];
            if (!edb_lit.getPredicate(position).equals(attribute)){
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (match)
            matchedLiterals.add(edb_lit);
    }
    indexedFactsWithJointVars.put(predicate, matchedLiterals);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try parsing all the positions before running the loop (storing them separatlely)

Comment: @Nadir: What do you mean of parsing positions?

Comment: Perform all this calcs `Integer.parseInt(teta[i][0]);` before the real loop

Comment: I've had another implementation before this that did not include parseInt statement. There is no difference!

Comment: edb_lit.getPredicate access a map or an array?

Comment: Teta is of a fixed lenght or it might vary?

Comment: Teta has maximum 10 members.

Comment: I was going to suggest to unroll the inner loop, but if lenght is not fixed you cannot do it

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely to be contention on data shared by the threads.  The fact that relative performance improves when you simulate local work in the threads is consistent with this, as simulation of work with a pause doesn't actually access any shared objects or resources.

Your code snippet doesn't provide enough information to be certain of additional detail, but it's possible that `indexedFactsWithAllFreeVars` is the resource that is being contended for, since if shared between threads it is likely, and should be, synchronized for access.  However, given the result with your simulated work, if there is actually going to be real work performed in the threads, and as long as that real work doesn't contend for shared resources, you may get your expected speedup in the real case, so this may not be a real issue..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I do not have any contention and shared data structure (indexedFactsWithAllFreeVars is not shared). I am sure about this because I have monitored my application states by JMC. Moreover, I have no more (real) work for threads! Threads are there only to perform query and fetch data from data structure.